# Why the function is returning garbage value?

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, return

Here is my full program:

**score.h**

```
#ifndef SCORE_H
#define SCORE_H

class Score 
{

private:

    int* ipScore;
    float fAverage;
    int iSize;

public:

    Score();

    void enterScores();
    void calcAverage();
    void output();

    void setSize();
    int getSize();

    void setScore();
    int* getScore();

    float getAverage();
};

#endif
```

**score.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "score.h"

using namespace std;

Score::Score()
{
}

void Score::enterScores()
{
    cout << "How many test scores needed: ";

    setSize();

    cout << endl;

    setScore();

    for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter score " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> ipScore[i];
    }

    cout << endl;

}

void Score::calcAverage()
{
    fAverage = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++)
    {
        fAverage = fAverage + ipScore[i];
    }

    fAverage = fAverage / getSize();
}

void Score::output()
{
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (getSize() - 1); j++)
        {
            if (ipScore[j] > ipScore[j + 1])
            {
                temp = ipScore[j];
                ipScore[j] = ipScore[j + 1];
                ipScore[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Sorted list of data entered is:- " << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < getSize(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Score " << i + 1 << ": " << ipScore[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "The average is: " << fAverage << endl;

    cout << endl;
}

void Score::setSize()
{
    cin >> iSize;
}

int Score::getSize()
{
    return iSize;
}

void Score::setScore()
{
    ipScore = new int[getSize()];
}

int* Score::getScore()
{
    return ipScore;
}

float Score::getAverage()
{
    return fAverage;
}
```

**curve1.h**

```
#ifndef CURVE1_H
#define CURVE1_H

#include "score.h"

class Curve1: public Score
{

public:

    Curve1();

    void curve();

};

#endif
```

**curve1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "curve1.h"

using namespace std;

Curve1::Curve1(): Score()
{
    cout << "Size was: " << getSize() << endl;
}

void Curve1::curve()
{
    cout << "Average score was: " << getAverage() << endl;  
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "curve1.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Score scoreObj;
    Curve1 curve1Obj;

    scoreObj.enterScores();

    scoreObj.calcAverage();

    scoreObj.output();

    curve1Obj.curve();

    return 0;
}
```

Firstly when I output the `iSize` and `fAverage` in `score.cpp`, they show the right values. But when I output them in `curve1.cpp`, they show garbage. :( Why is this happening?
Also when the curve object is called in the `main` function, the size cout statement is not shown. Please help!!!

Comment: They are 2 different objects?

Comment: Yes the Curve1 object is `curve1Obj` and Score object is `scoreObj`.

Comment: So why do you think that curve1Obj knows what values you've entered for scoreObj?

Comment: Because they are inherited ... maybe??

Comment: That doesn't mean that an object of type `Curve1` knows anything that you've done with an object of type `Score`. Only that `Curve1` inherits certain functions and variables from `Score`.

Comment: I don't know if I am wrong but aren't the values already set in `fAverage` and `iSize`? and that Curve1 is just calling `getAverage` and `getSize` that just output the already set values? Whats the role of object in it? To me that object is just calling the `curve` function which calls the `getSize` and `getAverage`. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: They're two different objects, they know nothing about each other as you haven't told either of them about the other.

Comment: Time to learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`). Also, compile with debugging info and almost all warnings: `g++ -Wall -g` ...

Comment: Well then maybe I should use the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my program, the actual problem was that creating `curve1Obj` of `Curve1` instance would result in creating another set of `iSize` and `fAverage` with default i.e. **garbage** values.
Previous values of `iSize` and `fAverage` were defined by `scoreObj` and couldn't be accessed by `curve1Obj`. So I figured out that there is no need for `scoreObj` as every thing is accessible with `curve1Obj`. Thanks for your contribution guys.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused with classes and instances of classes.

Say you have,

```
// This just defines a class. It does not create any instances of the class.
struct A
{
   A() : aVal(0) {}
   int aVal;
};

void foo()
{
   A a1; // Create instance of the class
   A a2; // Create another instance of the class.

   std::cout << a1.aVal << std::endl;  // 0
   std::cout << a2.aVal << std::endl;  // 0

   // Change the value of one instance.
   // It does not change the value of the other instance.
   a1.aVal = 10;
   std::cout << a1.aVal << std::endl;  // 10
   std::cout << a2.aVal << std::endl;  // still 0

   // Now change the value of the second instance.
   // Value of the first instance remains unchanged.
   a2.aVal = 20;
   std::cout << a1.aVal << std::endl;  // Still 10
   std::cout << a2.aVal << std::endl;  // 20
}
```

Now create a class `B` that is a sub-class of `A`.

```
struct B : public A
{
   B() : A(), bVal(0) {}
   int bVal;
};

void bar()
{
   // Create an instance of A and in instance of B
   A a1;
   B b1;

   std::cout << a1.aVal << std::endl; // 0
   std::cout << b1.aVal << std::endl; // 0
   std::cout << b1.bVal << std::endl; // 0

   // Change the value of a1. Values of b1 remain unchanged.
   a1.aVal = 20;
   std::cout << a1.aVal << std::endl; // 20
   std::cout << b1.aVal << std::endl; // Still 0
   std::cout << b1.bVal << std::endl; // Still 0

   // Change the values of b1. Value of a1 remain unchanged.
   b1.aVal = 30;
   b1.bVal = 40;

   std::cout << a1.aVal << std::endl; // Still 20
   std::cout << b1.aVal << std::endl; // 30
   std::cout << b1.bVal << std::endl; // 40
}
```

In your code you create an instance of `Score`, `scoreObj`, and an instance of `Curve1`, `curve1Obj`. The data of `scoreObj` and `curve1Obj` are independent. Modifying the data of `scoreObj` does not change the data of `curve1Obj` and vice versa.

Hope that makes things a little bit clear for you.

Comment: @R Sahu Thank you for your help. I got what I was doing wrong. :)

Comment: @SilverFalcon I'm glad I was able to help.